# Assignment algorithm variant

Tags: r, algorithm

I have a square matrix in R containing distances between cities:

```
set.seed(3)
x <- matrix(sample(1:15, 16, replace = TRUE), nrow = 4)
x
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3   10    9    9
#[2,]   13   10   10    9
#[3,]    6    2    8   14
#[4,]    5    5    8   13
```

Every row represents a city from which a courier can be sent, and every column represents a city where a package has to be delivered. All couriers have the same package, so they can be assigned to every other city.
Normally I would use the Hungarian algorithm in `clue::solve_LSAP()` to find an optimal assignment so that the total cost (in this case total distance) would be minimized:

```
y <- clue::solve_LSAP(x)
y
#Optimal assignment:
#1 => 1, 2 => 4, 3 => 2, 4 => 3
```

However, in this specific case I would like minimize the spread of the distances.
I have been searching for quite some time now, and I found the following [here in this book at page 270](https://books.google.nl/books?id=LiKNDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA270&lpg=PA270&dq=balanced+bottleneck+assignment&source=bl&ots=f9cOLSVcmd&sig=_eDIQiXylMHPLwlTUb1reMYDhEM&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-5tCpp5DTAhVGKMAKHc3bBYAQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) (and something similar [here in this book at page 195](https://books.google.nl/books?id=FH6_Bb82I_UC&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=martello%20pulleyblank%20assignment%20algorithm&source=bl&ots=dKkERz6Rht&sig=9IQ4WB0vqqfXfVVESoILedoVauc&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT2qG8ipDTAhVqDMAKHaWoCW0Q6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

[image]

So the stated objective is to minimize the difference between the maximum and minimum assigned distance, which is exactly what I am looking for. The assignment of the Hungarian algorithm gives the following difference between maximum and minimum distance:

```
distances <- x[cbind(1:4, y)]
max(distances) - min(distances)
#[1] 7
```

However, the best assignment to minimize the new objective is (this solution was found by brute force):

```
#Optimal assignment to minimize the new objective:
#1 => 2, 2 => 4, 3 => 1, 4 => 3
yNew <- c(2, 4, 1, 3)
distancesNew <- x[cbind(1:4, yNew)]
max(distancesNew) - min(distancesNew)
#[1] 4
```

So clearly, the Hungarian algorithm doesn't give the desired solution.

Now my question: is there any existing R code that finds an optimal assignment by minimizing the objective mentioned above (the difference between the maximum and minimum assigned cost value)? Or maybe some R code with an algorithm that achieves a similar result?

Those books I mentioned describe the algorithm I want, but 1) they both start with the solution of the bottleneck assignment problem (an algorithm for which I couldn't find R code either) and 2) implementing this algorithm (and possibly also the bottleneck assignment algorithm) myself would be far from ideal.